# How to access vertx HttpClientRequest fields?

Tags: java, vert.x

I am writing a web server in `java` using `vertx`.
I use the server as a proxy to other services, and I'm the the testing stage. I want to know that I have created the request correctly with custom tokens and headers.
But, I cant manage to find a way to receive the properties upon creation.

```
HttpClientRequest clientRequest = vertx.createHttpClient().request(HttpMethod.GET,80,"host","/path?query=value");
```

When I try to read the host `clientRequest.getHost()` I receive a `null`, but in debug, reading its values, I can see a property named `delegate` which contains all of its data.
How can I access those values from `clientRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

What you see in debug is:

```
((HttpClientRequestImpl) req).host
```

While `getHost()` method actually returns you `hostHeader`

For testing purposes I suggest to cast your `HttpClientRequest` to `HttpClientRequestImpl`, as it will expose more data.

If everything else fails, you can also fall back to reflection, of course.